# login to a specific website using python

Tags: python, authentication, web

I want to login the website at http://www.ppdai.com/Login.aspx
I already tried some solution such as request, twill, and cookie jar, it seems none of them work.
the user account list as follows:

```
username: zhonghao007
password: zonghao0915
```

Once you login succeed, you can visit another website to check your personal info at http://www.ppdai.com/account1/lend.aspx

thanks for any help
here is the requests code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()# Get local session of firefox
browser.get("http://www.ppdai.com/login.aspx") # Load page
userid = browser.find_element_by_id('txtUserName')
userid.send_keys('zhonghao007')
passw = browser.find_element_by_id('txtPassword')
passw.send_keys('zonghao0915')
signin = browser.find_element_by_id('btnLogin')
signin.click()
```

Comment: Mechanize will do the trick You can take a look at this page
wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/

Comment: The posted webdriver code should work, but your username/password are incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code for that page you can see the form has the following structure:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="login.aspx" id="form1">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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" />

<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWBQLh9ro4AqXVsrMJArWptJELAoLch4YMApCjwqsN3xZOGR6YaITqg9kNkVxXG+bnVLo=" />

<input name="txtUserName" type="text" >
<input name="txtPassword" type="password" />
<input type="image" name="btnLogin" id="btnLogin"  />
<input type="hidden" name="HiddenField1" id="HiddenField1" value="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129431/login-to-a-specific-website-using-python" />
        </form>
```

So you should be able to do a POST to http://www.ppdai.com/login.aspx with the following data

```
r = requests.post('http://www.ppdai.com/login.aspx', data={
    '__VIEWSTATE': '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',
    '__EVENTVALIDATION': '/wEWBQLh9ro4AqXVsrMJArWptJELAoLch4YMApCjwqsN3xZOGR6YaITqg9kNkVxXG+bnVLo='
    'txtUserName': 'zhonghao007',
    'txtPassword': 'zonghao0915',
    'HiddenField1': 'http://www.somereferring-url.com'
    }
)
```

viewstate and eventvalidation look like they are generated with every page request, and are probably used as for some sort of CSRF validation. So you will probably need to first request the page, find the values for those fields, and then make the POST request using the freshly generated ones. You will also need to make sure you are passing the session cookie.

Alternatively you can use Selenium webdriver to directly drive a real browser. That means it will definitely work.

Comment: It seems that __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION are encoded with `base64`. Decoding __VIEWSTATE produces the website from which you accessed the login page among other things.

Comment: Yuck! Why the hell do people pass state around in the DOM like that?

Comment: Who knows? There is some javascript (from google analytics) in there as well.

Comment: I have tried Selenium webdriver, but the website blocked my access as an unsaftey login. still cannot work

Comment: Well, if they've blocked your IP address then there's not much you can do. But that seems unlikely. I would post a new question with the webdriver code you are using and the error you are getting.

Comment: [code]from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()# Get local session of firefox
browser.get("http://www.ppdai.com/login.aspx") # Load page
userid = browser.find_element_by_id('txtUserName')
userid.send_keys('zhonghao007')
passw = browser.find_element_by_id('txtPassword')
passw.send_keys('zonghao0915')
signin = browser.find_element_by_id('btnLogin')
signin.click()

Comment: _italic_ **bold** `code` from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()# Get local session of firefox
browser.get("http://www.ppdai.com/login.aspx") # Load page
userid = browser.find_element_by_id('txtUserName')
userid.send_keys('zhonghao007')
passw = browser.find_element_by_id('txtPassword')
passw.send_keys('zonghao0915')
signin = browser.find_element_by_id('btnLogin')
signin.click()

Comment: browser = webdriver.Firefox()# Get local session of firefox
browser.get("http://www.ppdai.com/login.aspx") # Load page
userid = browser.find_element_by_id('txtUserName')
userid.send_keys('zhonghao007')
passw = browser.find_element_by_id('txtPassword')
passw.send_keys('zonghao0915')
signin = browser.find_element_by_id('btnLogin')
signin.click()

Comment: Post a NEW question, I'm not even going to bother trying to read unindented Python code.

Comment: @aychedee refer to the original question, I already put the code there